# How do I synchronize an ECG signal?

Tags: matlab

I have an ECG signal with several beats. I would like to create a single beat from the entire signal that is made of all the beats on top of each other, synchronized by their maximum. I have the indices of the R points.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us what you have already done.

Comment: I only have the QRS detection algorithm, don't know how to do the synchronization, was hoping you could help